# How to press a next button and focus another text field input?

Tags: react-native, react-hook-form

#### Version react hook form

- ^7.27.0

#### What I tried to follow and without successful

[react hook form - Discussions 7818](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/discussions/7818)
[react hook form - Issues 230](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/issues/230)

#### About what I have

I have 4 text field components at my screen, the name of each text field is `name, documentation, email, password` and I would like to know how can I setup some configuration that it will be pressed the NEXT button at keyboard and will focus the following text fields?

An example that I have inside at my component file, again I would like to press the next button and the next component that I will config, will be focus.

```js
<TextField
  name="name"
  label={I18n.t('registerPersonal.fullNameLabel')}
  placeholder={I18n.t('registerPersonal.fullNameInput')}
  icon={<TypographyIcon fill={!!errors.name && theme.colors.attention} />}
  error={errors.name?.message}
  errors={errors}
  control={control}
  returnKeyType="next"
/>

<TextField
  name="documentation"
  label={I18n.t('registerPersonal.documentIdentificationLabel')}
  placeholder={I18n.t('registerPersonal.documentIdentificationInput')}
  icon={
    <DocumentIcon
      fill={!!errors.documentation && theme.colors.attention}
    />
  }
  error={errors.documentation?.message}
  control={control}
  returnKeyType="next"
/>
```

Some properties that I get at my personal hook

```js
const {
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors, isValid }
  } = useForm({ resolver: yupResolver(schema) })
```

My component TextField

```js
import { TextInputProps, Text } from 'react-native'
import { Control, useController } from 'react-hook-form'

import { Container, Wrapper, TextInput, Label } from './styles'

import theme from '../../global/styles/theme'

type TextFieldProps = {
  placeholder?: string
  label?: string
  icon?: React.ReactNode
  error?: string
  errors?: {
    [x: string]: any
  }
  name: string
  control: Control
} & TextInputProps

export function TextField(props: TextFieldProps) {
  const { placeholder, label, icon, error, errors, name, control, ...rest } =
    props

  const { field } = useController({
    control,
    defaultValue: '',
    name
  })

  return (
    <>
      <Container>
        {!!label && <Label>{label}</Label>}
        <Wrapper hasLabel={!!label} hasError={!!error}>
          {!!icon && icon}
          <TextInput
            value={field.value}
            onChangeText={field.onChange}
            placeholder={error ? error : placeholder}
            placeholderTextColor={
              error ? theme.colors.attention : theme.colors.grayColor
            }
            {...rest}
          />
        </Wrapper>
        {errors && errors.name && errors.name.type === 'matches' && (
          <Text>{errors.name.message}</Text>
        )}
      </Container>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your component must include ref prop like

```
     <TextInput
        ref={inputRef} // this one
        value={field.value}
        onChangeText={field.onChange}
        placeholder={error ? error : placeholder}
        placeholderTextColor={
          error ? theme.colors.attention : theme.colors.grayColor
        }
        {...rest}
      />
```

then, you need to create ref from parent for each field

```
const emailRef = useRef(null);
const passwordRef = useRef(null);
```

after this, you need to add the props that is

```
onSubmitEditing={() => passwordRef.current.focus()} // to auto focus password field
```

finally,

```
    <TextField
       onSubmitEditing={() => passwordRef.current.focus()} // here
       name="name"
       label={I18n.t('registerPersonal.fullNameLabel')}
       placeholder={I18n.t('registerPersonal.fullNameInput')}
       icon={<TypographyIcon fill={!!errors.name && theme.colors.attention} />}
       error={errors.name?.message}
       errors={errors}
       control={control}
       returnKeyType="next"
     />
```